# How to include all PHP files in directory?

Tags: php, module, include

I have a directory with php files, those files are auto-updating every day. Sometimes I add another (new) PHP file.

What is the best way to include all php files from the directory?

1. List all files in directory?
2. Create some config file with filenames? (need to update every time)
3. List files in main php? (edit main file every time  I add new php file to include)
4. Other?

Thank you!

Comment: Including files like that can be very dangerous. At least create some kind of protection mechanism to allow only valid files to be included.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I always do that like this where you would put your include normally but then in a foreach:

```
foreach(glob('dir/*.php') as $file) {
     include_once $file;
}
```

that is maybe not the best way, it is always a good idea to create a list maybe an array of filepaths and then put that in the foreach like:

```
$includes = array(
   'path/to/file.php',
   'path/to/another/file.php'
);

foreach($includes as $file) {
     include_once $file;
}
```

then whenever you add a file you can add one to that list and it will be included

Answer (score 5):

If the files are classes you can try:

```
function __autoload($class_name) 
{
  require_once 'dir/' . $class_name . '.php';
}
```

see [Autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)

Answer (score 1):

The `scandir()`function will return an array with all the files in a directory:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php